# Filtering Fibonacci numbers for elements meeting certain criteria

Tags: filtering, homework, timing

> Write a code that selects in less than two seconds from every 123rd of the first 33,333 even Fibonaci numbers; those which contain the digits 2, 3, 6, 7, and 8 and also contains the digit 1 more than 123 times. (The code should also compute all the Fibonacci numbers similar to the previous questions.)

Code used previously:

```
Fibonacci @ Range[0., 99996., 3.]
```

Comment: You might look up the documentation for `Select`. Please write a post title that is a little more descriptive of what you are asking for, and let us know exactly where you are struggling in this problem!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, User9495! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.